# want to use active directory authentication to log in to web base system

Tags: php, windows, active-directory, ldap

I am developing a php web-based system. For that system I want to use single sign on system. That means, if some one logged in to windows computer with his correct username and password then he can be signed in to my web based system without typing his password and username again.

I'm developing my web based system to run on a linux operating system. The other computers are running Windows operating system and use active directory. So where should I start? 
Can some one give me a guide?

Comment: try to use something other than AD, especially if you have a large number of users...

Comment: @AaronGong Active Directory is the standard user platform for many businesses. Building an SSO enabled application would then require integration with AD. Usually the developers aren't in a position to dictate directory services platforms unless the place is very small.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, I had an experience where AD was tied to user registration, and the site happens to have heavy traffic where anyone can register and subscribe, felt it was a little overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at this class:

http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

It's as simple as:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/adLDAP.php');
$adldap = new adLDAP();
/* Some code here */

$adldap->close();
$adldap->setAdminUsername('Admin.User');
$adldap->setAdminPassword('SomePassword');
$adldap->connect();
/* Some code here */

$adldap->user()->authenticate($username, $password);
```

$username and $password in the authenticate() call are what you get from your user and you'll need to handle any errors related to auth as you would any normal auth system.

http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_user_functions

Comment: The adLDAP or the [AD-X](https://github.com/Alaneor/AD-X) libraries merely provide a means of authenticating against Active Directory. They do **NOT** provide SSO functionality. The users still need to provide their usernames and passwords.

Comment: @ShadowWalker For many companies, SSO is described as using a central set of credentials to login to a system. One could argue semantically that SSO means login once, access all available resources for the day. It's not been my experience that many people using the term "SSO" actually intend to build that.

Comment: In [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) I trust.:-) Even if an application/website uses a central identity for authentication ( the AD credentials ) as long as the user has to provide those credentials it cannot be called "SSO-enabled".

Comment: @ShadowWalker Fair enough.